# How to create an Index Array with references from a MATCH Function

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two arrays. The second array is a lookup array for the first array and returns the row where there is a match.

```
=IFERROR(MATCH(B2:B9,A2:A9, 0),"")
```

Then the integers in this new array are used as the index for another new array whose values are the Index of the matching value in the lookup array separated by blank elements for indexes not referenced.

[image: Problem Image]

I fear that this is simple problem that I am overthinking. Thank you for your help.

Originally, I tried comparing the two arrays directly, but this obviously didn't work because only elements in the same ROW() are compared. Then I tried creating a Boolean Array, but am not sure how to implement it to find the original element index in the lookup array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change the places of the ranges:

```
=IFERROR(MATCH(A2:A9, B2:B9, 0),"")
```

[image]

Comment: Shorter One: `=IFNA(XMATCH(A2:A9,B2:B9),"")` or `=XLOOKUP(A2:A9,B2:B9,ROW(B2:B9)-1,"")`

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya That assumes that A2 and B2 are filled with a spill formula.  I do not see where the OP states that.  I see them using `Array` but that may just be them using `Array` when referring to a Range.

Comment: Alright Sir, I thought OP said array that is why. Understood now sir thanks again!

Comment: I knew it was something dumb :( -Thanks